# Set request property content type to raw byte data?

Tags: java, http, audio, connection

I have a HttpURLConnection which I send audio to.
I use

```
setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "audio/x-flac; rate=48000");
```

to specify the type of the audio I am sending. I am supposed to receive a string of whatever the audio file says.

It works when I get a byte array of the audio file and send that but I want to be able to send audio taken from my microphone as a byte array but I don't know how to specify that.

Or I could send a wav file but I tried it with a test file using "audio/wav" and that still doesn't work.

The error I get when it doesn't work is

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=speech2text&lang=en-US&maxresults=10
```

The line it refers to is

```
connection.getInputStream();
```

Thanks.

Comment: 500 is `500 Internal Server Error`. Depends how your server is implemented.

Comment: I'm connecting to Google's speech server
https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=speech2text&lang=en-US&maxresults=10